How to do a Proximity text search, 2 + words?
What is a Linux terminal command to do a Proximity text search?
Search a directory, recursively, for files that contain :
2 words or more within
99 characters of each other
any order of above words.
example1:
search by : city and first name
Berlin
Bob
Above input finds a file with
Bob Smith
123 Main Street Apt. 101
Berlin Ohio USA  54321
Phone ...
email ...
Question -- inspired by:
example2 is working, on web page, not desired Local disk:
search for 2 words:
living
soul
https://www.biblegateway.com/quicksearch/?quicksearch=living+soul&resultspp=250&version=NIV
finds 4 verses
here is 1 quote in reverse order of 2 word input:
soul
living
Psalm 84:2
My soul yearns, even faints, for the courts of the Lord;
my heart and my flesh cry out for the living God.
Instead of above web page Proximity text search ...
What is a Linux terminal command to do a,
2 + word,
Proximity text search on a Local disk?
using
OS: Kubuntu 22.04.4 LTS x86_64
to display above:
neofetch --stdout |grep 'OS:'
--

You may easily achieve this using a combination of 'find-, 'exec' and 'grep'.
The logic is the following:

Find all files recursively within a specific path/directory
For each file, execute a grep command
For each grepped content, also include some lines after the match (for example 2).

The command will be (in your linux shell):
find /some/path/ -type f -exec egrep -hi -A2 "bob|berlin" {} +;

Note that, with grep:

Option A: to show X lines after the match
Option B: to show X lines before the match
Option C: to show X lines before and after the match

Hope it helps.
Alternative 1
If you want to display the matched data from a file that have BOTH the values you are looking for, you may try this:
grep -lri "bob" $(grep -lri "berlin" /some/path/) | xargs egrep -Hi -A2 "bob|berlin"

Some explanations:

The piece of  code grep -lri "bob" $(grep -lri "berlin" /some/path/) will return all filepaths matching both the strings you are looking for (bob & berlin).
The piece of code xargs egrep -Hi -A2 "bob|berlin" takes the input filepaths (xargs) and display any line containing bob or berlin (case unsensitive) + 2 lines after + the filepaths where lines originate from.
Option l (grep): return filenames instead of contents.
Option r (grep): search recursively over a folder
Option i (grep): case unsensitive. Grep will match the search whatever the LetTerCaSe found.
Option H (grep): prefix the output with the filepath from which the result is matched.

Hope it helps more.
Alternative 2
The previous commands does not properly handle filenames having spaces. The xargs command will handle names with spaces as two separate files, and the grep would result in the error like: "No such file or directory".
The following command may help resolve this issue by handling filenames properly (even if they have spaces in it)
find /some/path -type f -exec grep -li bob {} + |xargs -I% grep -li berlin % |xargs -I% egrep -Hi -A2 "bob|berlin" %

This command line is not necessarily very optimized, but has the merit of working

petitradisgris typed Hope it helps. -- It partially helps.
used: egrep --version # grep (GNU grep) 3.7 # command1 used:
find . -type f -exec egrep -hi -A2 "bob|berlin" {} +;

command1 shows a false positive, because command1 finds text with
bob = string1 but that file did not have
berlin = string2 -- thus false positive.
Output is not the file but the contents showing
bob and berlin.
This means the output is a wall of text with no reference as to
which files have that text.  --


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637882/how-can-i-use-grep-to-show-just-filenames-on-linux

As for the mismatches, you'll need to provide accurate examples of what should be matched and what not.

see example 1 .

Hello joseph. I believe that i understood better your need with your comment, so i have made an EDIT to my post. False positive 1 resolved: only data from files having BOTH strings will be displayed. 2nd false positive: resolved by using the -H argument to grep, giving a prefix which is the flenames for each matched line

Hello petitradisgris.  Command issued was:
grep -lri "bob" $(grep -lri "berlin" . ) | xargs egrep -Hi -A2 "bob|berlin" _
many errors like:
grep: Proximity: No such file or directory _ see next post ...

This looks promising.
More experimenting to do with: ripgrep
sudo apt install ripgrep _
rg -V   # ripgrep 13.0.0 _
example1:
rg -lU --multiline-dotall 'foo.*bar|bar.*foo' _ example2:
rg -lU --multiline-dotall 'bob.*berlin|berlin.*bob' _
see,
grep or ripgrep: How to find only files that match multiple patterns (not only on the same line)?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59052703/grep-or-ripgrep-how-to-find-only-files-that-match-multiple-patterns-not-only-o
More experimenting to do ...

helo joseph22. Your error is weird. I do exactly the same command as you, and it works like a charm without any errors. What shell are you using ? echo $SHELL, what version $SHELL --version, maybe it is an issue related to your file access permissions..may you try to run it as 'root' just to confirm it ? How do you run your script ? try to run it like: bash yourscript.shto force bash interpreter and see if you got the same result

Hello petitradisgris.  Thank you for following up.
My response is slow because no notification you commented. _
echo $SHELL gives
/bin/bash _
$SHELL --version | head -n 1 gives
GNU bash, version 5.1.16(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) _
and same error as root, meaning
sudo -i gives
root@XX:~# and goto directory on usb disk VFAT with
many files including bob and berlin in one file
grep -lri "bob" $(grep -lri "berlin" . ) | xargs egrep -Hi -A2 "bob|berlin" gives
grep: Proximity: No such file or directory

okay. other question. Do you have some filenames with spaces ? like "this is a file.txt".
If this is the case, the issue is probably due to the fact that xargs is considering it as multiple entries (instead of one) and then failing...

Look at my post @joseph22 and try the Alternative 2 commandline. THis may resolve your issue.

petitradisgris typed,
Do you have some filenames with spaces ? 
Answer Yes.
i am aware of :
detox -V   # detox 1.4.5
fixes filenames with spaces plus other problems. A bash example:
detox -s iso8859_1 "$FILE1"   # detox = cleanup filename 

While in the directory with the pattern, with the 2 strings bob and berlin, ran:
find . -type f -exec grep -li bob {} + |xargs -I% grep -li berlin % |xargs -I% egrep -Hi -A2 "bob|berlin" "%"
and it worked.  Your command found a filename with bob and berlin. Success!
SuccessThenProblem1:  found same filename many times,
Guessing it finds the same filename for each occurance of pattern bob and berlin inside 1 file.

While many directories away from pattern bob and berlin , ran:
find . -type f -exec grep -li bob {} + |xargs -I% grep -li berlin % |xargs -I% egrep -Hi -A2 "bob|berlin" "%" 
SuccessThenProblem2:
xargs: unmatched single quote; by default quotes are special to xargs unless you use the -0 option

okay and like that ? find . -type f -exec grep -li bob {} + |xargs -I% grep -li berlin % |xargs -I% egrep -Hi -A2 "bob|berlin" %  .

Same Problems with
find . -type f -exec grep -li bob {} + |xargs -I% grep -li berlin % |xargs -I% egrep -Hi -A2 "bob|berlin" %  . – 
same Problem1 and Problem2.
